# dot dot(..) pathing doesnt work on java new file with linux running jenkins

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins

```
 File f = new File(basedir, "../src/main");
```

I have this in a maven build on Jenkins. It's being used to generate files. It works when building on my local machine(windows 7) but doesn't work when i run it on Linux. It looks like it's taking the .. as a literal folder path and not going back a directory. The error is:

```
 Embedded error: /path/to/Jenkins/project/target/../src/main/xsd/common.xsd (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: If `basedir` is a `File` object, you can try `basedir.getParent()` and the relative path without dots.

Comment: In general you should not be generating files into your `src` tree. It's better that it is kept pristine for source control. Most modern maven plugins will automatically generate files into the `target/generated-sources/...` directory and add them to the list of java sources or resources as needed for the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `basedir.getParent()` works.